# Cannot convert type string to System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.RuleAction in c#

Tags: c#

```
if (!ruleSet.Validate(rv))
{ 
    List<System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.Rule> rulesList = new List<System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.Rule>(); 
    rulesList = ruleSet.Rules.ToList();
    foreach (System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.Rule rr in rulesList) 
    { 
        System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.Rule rules = new System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.Rule(); 
        string ruleName = rr.Name; 
        string condtion = rr.Condition.ToString(); 
        string s1 = rr.ThenActions.ToString(); 
        string[] s2 = s1.Split('='); 
        string rightString = s2[1]; 
        string append = "=Convert.ToString(" + rightString + ")"; 
        string result = s2[0] + append; 
        rules.ThenActions=result;//Error:cannot convert string to ruleaction 
    } 
}
```

How to convert type string to System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.RuleAction in c#..
    i want to modify the ThenActions,ElseActions,Condition in code behind without opening the RulesEditor.

Comment: Does it make sense to make that convertion? Without code we don't even know what you are doing!

Comment: If you want any answers, at least put in some effort in formatting the code.

Comment: Why don't you change the `ThenActions` instead of converting it to string and so on.

Comment: @PatrickHofman is right, you can do `rules.ThenActions = rr.ThenActions`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your actions, don't convert it to a `string`, but change the [`RuleAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.rules.ruleaction(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Depending on the type of the action you should cast it and change it:

```
var ra = (RuleStatementAction)rr.ThenActions[0];
ra.XXX = yourChange;
rules.ThenActions[0] = ra;
```